# Taylor series for cos(x) in matlab

Tags: matlab, trigonometry, taylor-series

**I have a simple question. I want to write Taylor series expansion for cos(x).**
**And I wrote that codes**

```
x=input('Please input an angle in degrees: ');
cosx=1;
for i=1:1:x
addterm = (-1)^i*(x.^(2*i))/factorial(2*i);
cosx = cosx + addterm;
end
 a=['The value of cosine of ',num2str(x),' degrees is ', num2str(cosx)];
 disp(a)
```

**But that code did not give true result.Why?**

Comment: Why is the terms number depending on the angle (x) ?? It should depend on the required accuracy. And I believe it's radians, not degrees..

Comment: But I have degrees values

Comment: Then you need to convert it. Or change the expansion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Taylor series you use needs `x` to be expressed in radians. After the `input` multiply `x` by `π/180` to convert degrees to radians. Also you need to have many iterations, not just `x`. Try `for i=1:1:10` because factorial grows very fast.

Answer (score 0):

Because you only let your `for` loop run from 1 to `x`; probably you want to let it run to a specific natural number, eg:

```
for i=1:1:100
```

to get the first 100 terms of the Taylor series.
Also, you can omit the step width if it's 1, so

```
for i=1:100
```

works just as well.

EDIT: I assume you're entering `x` in radians, right?